# How to read a file of 12Mb where each line is of 3Mb in java? I need to read line by line

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying BufferedReader but unable to store the entire line into the String. Any other way to store it into a datatype.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(getInputStream());
    BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = ir.readLine()) != null) {
     //do stuff with "line"
    }
```

If that is not possible, can i change the input for a map function in MapReduce Framework? Can i use one mapper for each file in the directory instead of line by line as input?

Comment: And what do you want to do with one "line"? Can't you use a `CharSequence` instead?

Comment: Have you tried to simply `Files.readAllLines()`?

Comment: @assylias .. The problem is I was not able to store one line(3Mb data) in a String. Files.readAllLines() gives me the list<String> for all the lines.

Comment: @fge I am writing a mapReduce Program where the mapper is provided with the input  line by line from the files. How can we change the input of the mapper to CharSequence from Text.

Comment: @satyakarthik it returns a list of lines, so each line is represented by one string. Isn't it what you asked for?